# Mouse hover style gets removed on click of a row in cell table in gwt

Tags: gwt

Currently , I am applying mouse hover style to highlight the row of a celltable by using below code snippet.

```
int rowCount = this.getRowCount();
for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
            TableRowElement rowElement = this.getRowElement(i);
            rowElement.addClassName("selected-row");
        }

.selected-row:hover{
  background-color: #DFE8F6;
}
```

When i click a row in the cell table, the hover style gets removed, and is not highlighting the row. Can someone suggest please how to retain the hover style, even after clicking of a row.  Please give some examples.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a row, the table is refreshed, which removes your style.

GWT already applies a special style to a selected row. If you don't like the way it looks, you can override GWT's CSS class rather than trying to add your own.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add the background-color in a mouse down event as well.